# What is difference between URL.init(string: "") and URL(string: "")?

Tags: swift

What is difference between

```
 URL.init(string: "")
```

and

```
 URL(string: "")
```

Which is the better way?

Comment: The second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way you stated uses an Initializer.

Initializers are called to create a new instance of a particular type. In its simplest form, an initializer is like an instance method with no parameters.

This means that they are used for:

- To create an initial value.
- To assign default property value within the property definition.
- To initialize an instance for a particular data type 'init()' is used. No arguments are passed inside the init() function.

Therefore if you just want to use the data in the same instance you should use the first second method.

If you want to have the URL in anther instance and set it as a default value for your string you should use the first one.

But ultimately they will both do the same thing.